# Does a falling creature provoke Opportunity Attacks on the way down?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack

I'm in a D&D4e game right now, and in the current combat there are some flying creatures which may soon be knocked prone by PC #1.  As part of being knocked prone, a flying creature falls to the ground.  As they fall, the creatures may pass within melee range of PC #2 who is currently on the ground.

Would PC #2 get an Opportunity Attack in this scenario, as a creature leaves a square adjacent (elevated by one square) to him?

For reference, here's the "Moving Provokes" clause of the Opportunity Attack rule:

> Moving Provokes: If an enemy leaves a square adjacent to you, you can make an opportunity attack against that enemy. However, you can’t make one if the enemy shifts or teleports or is forced to move away by a pull, a push, or a slide.

Are there any other rules that apply to this scenario, which one should be aware of?

Comment: I would argue that falling via prone would definitely count as "forced movement"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the *Rules Compendium*, p209

> **No Opportunity Actions Triggered:**
>
> When a creature falls past an enemy, the creature does not trigger opportunity actions, such as opportunity attacks, from that enemy that are triggered by movement."

Answer (score 7):

I believe this would fall into the category of forced movement. The enemy did not choose to fall out of the sky, and thus would not be subject to opportunity attacks.