# Forced/involuntary movement and OAs

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement, opportunity-actions

The basics:
Moving away from a threatened square provokes an Opportunity Action.

The wrinkles:

- Certain forms of voluntary movement (shifts,
  teleports) specifically do not
  provoke OAs.
- Being pushed, pulled, or slid by someone else's power (forced movement) also do not provoke OAs.

The question:

- What if the movement is involuntary, but not forced by another PC or NPC? For instance, falling due to failing (or skipping) an athletics/acrobatics check, being swept away by the current, or other terrain hazard?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that all OA's can be avoided. If someone provokes an OA, they did so by their own choice.

Comment: While the rules say it doesn't provoke an Opportunity Attack, there's nothing preventing a house rule. Personally, I think think it (situationally) makes sense. Falling? Probably not. Pushed past a monster? Probably. Pulled away from a monster? Probably not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re: Falling: [Does a falling creature provoke Opportunity Attacks on the way down?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6475/does-a-falling-creature-provoke-opportunity-attacks-on-the-way-down)

Based on this, and the lack of OoAs on forced movement, I would assume that other terrain-based forced movement would not provoke OoAs either.